# Malfunction of Gnosis safe-Infrastructure app during long-term test

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have been running the Gnosis Safe-Infrastructure app for over a month, conducting a sample test on the Geoli chain.

Initially, it worked properly about a month ago, but currently, it is not functioning as expected. For instance, simple transactions such as "Send tokens" are not working and get cancelled.

Finally, I checked the admin panel of the transaction service and discovered something is wrong as shown in the picture.

1. The latest block number in "Internal txs" is not updating and remains the old number of 9046941, whereas it should be more than 9109942.
2. The latest date in "Internal txs" is not updating and remains the old date of May 23, even though it should be June 2.

#### Internal txs

http://localhost:8000/txs/admin/history/internaltx/
[image]

###### *cf*. Multisig transactions

http://localhost:8000/txs/admin/history/multisigtransaction/
[image]

#### System -- AWS EC2 (c5a.8xlarge)

- Number of vCPUs: 32
- RAM: 64 GiB
- Volume: 128 GiB

#### Docker terminal messages

[image]

## Questions

- Why did this issue occur?
- What steps can be taken to resolve it?

Comment: I've never used this, but if the block numbers are old, then the RPC node is out of sync with the blockchain. Can you change the provider?

Comment: Due to cost issues, I had to terminate the instance, which means I cannot change the provider at this time. The configuration of this app aligns with the information stated on [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147811/run-the-safe-global-safe-infrastructure-service-for-a-sample-test), where the public RPC URL of https://goerli.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161 remains valid to this day.