# Run the safe-global/safe-infrastructure service

Tags: gnosis-safe

The question is the same as here [Run the safe-global/safe-infrastructure service for a sample test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147811/run-the-safe-global-safe-infrastructure-service-for-a-sample-test).

It was done all steps, but the answer did not help to resolve the problem. So we still get the error during indexing/creating the wallet process:[image]
CGW logs returned error `Code 600: Error fetching Safe info (42: )`
Logs:

```
[2023-09-04T08:04:53Z INFO  _] Response succeeded.
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z INFO  rocket::server] GET /v1/chains/1230/safes/0xD29e6bAF19795291724B1766fbd1F04dcb76b5bB:
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z INFO  _] Matched: (get_safe_info) GET /v1/chains/<chain_id>/safes/<safe_address>
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z ERROR safe_client_gateway::utils::errors] ERR::404::/v1/chains/1230/safes/0xD29e6bAF19795291724B1766fbd1F04dcb76b5bB::ApiErrorMessage: code:42; message:Some(""); arguments:None
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z INFO  _] Outcome: Success
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z INFO  safe_client_gateway::monitoring::performance] MT::GET::/v1/chains/<chain_id>/safes/<safe_address>::1::404::/v1/chains/1230/safes/0xD29e6bAF19795291724B1766fbd1F04dcb76b5bB::1230::167.233.10.221
[2023-09-04T08:05:00Z INFO  _] Response succeeded.
```

Master copy was added manually in admin:
[image: Master copy was added manually in admin]

Also, SafeProxyFactory was added manually in admin:
[image: SafeProxyFactory was added manually in admin]

What are we missing? Could anyone help to understand the issue 42 without the message?
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Does it never resolve? I believe in the creation flow the UI polls the CGW until the account is available.

Comment: @mikheevm I'm, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: When you create a safe in the UI, it takes some time for the backend to index it, so it's totally expected to see a few 404s until it gets indexed

Comment: @mikheevm I got it, it does never resolve. We were waiting for 24 hours and even 1+ week. What are the issues here might be?

Comment: We found the reason of the errors. Thank you for your help! https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/154160/124073

Comment: awesome, thank you for leaving your solution for others 

Answer (score 1):

1. The first problem was the wrong RPC_NODE_URL (where the wrong address was specified).
2. Then the following problem: 2 records were created for the history chain for the transaction service - but there must be 1 Tx Service per Chain, with different workers, PostgreSQL, Redis and RabbitMQ.. https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/tree/main
3. So, we deleted the entry from the database and the errors in logs disappeared, after that, all workers that were shut down started to work without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Will add more information

Here is log from CGW service

```
[2023-09-05T10:36:54Z ERROR safe_client_gateway::utils::errors] ERR::404::/v1/chains/1230/safes/0xD29e6bAF19795291724B1766fbd1F04dcb76b5bB::ApiErrorMessage: code:1337; message:Some(""); arguments:None
[2023-09-05T10:36:54Z INFO  _] Outcome: Success
[2023-09-05T10:36:54Z INFO  safe_client_gateway::monitoring::performance] MT::GET::/v1/chains/<chain_id>/safes/<safe_address>::46::404::/v1/chains/1230/safes/0xD29e6bAF19795291724B1766fbd1F04dcb76b5bB::1230::167.233.10.221
[2023-09-05T10:36:54Z INFO  _] Response succeeded.
```

Maybe it can help

Comment: Yes, there are two errors, 42 and 1337. 1337 Appears once at first time when requesting the GET  `/cgw/v1/chains/1230/safes/0x04202a..` , but 42 errors appears all the time after for the same endpoint